# WordPress object for comments frame

Tags: single, terms

For two days I have tried to make this code work. I want to add a comment frame in `single.php`. I got this code to put it in the single page's template:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf­-8">
initFrame({ app_id: 'xxx' ,
object_id: 'ARTICLE_ID' ,
object_title: 'ARTICLE_TITLE' ,
object_content: 'ARTICLE_CONTENT' ,
object_url: 'ARTICLE_URL' ,
arguments_container: 'comment' ,
width: '610' })
</script>
```

and they said: Replace strings with some logic:

- ARTICLE_ID: id of the article in your website.
- ARTICLE_TITLE: title of the article
- ARTICLE_CONTENT: body content of the article
- ARTICLE_URL: the url to the article
- DIV_ID: the div id where Naqeshny arguments box appears

The question is:  what should I write in ARTICLE_ID, ARTICLE_TITLE, etc. to change in every topic I write on my website?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So long as you're in [the loop](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop), you can just use the standard [template tags](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags):

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf­8">
    initFrame({
        app_id: "",
        object_id: <?php the_ID() ?>,
        object_title: "<?php the_title_attribute() ?>",
        object_content: '<?php echo wp_trim_words( strip_shortcodes( striptags( get_the_content() ) ), 45 ) ?>',
        object_url: "<?php the_permalink() ?>",
        arguments_container: "comment-naqeshny",
        width: 610
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but are you sure about object_content: '<?php echo esc_js( get_the_content() ) ?>',

because when i see the source i got this:
object_content: '&lt;img class=&quot;aligncenter size-medium wp-image-32681&quot; alt=&quot;sisi.net&quot; src=&quot;http://www.mywebsite.com/efp-news/uploads/2014/03/sisi.net_-424x238.jpg&quot; width=&quot;424&quot; height=&quot;238&quot; /&gt;\n&lt;p dir=&quot;RTL&quot;&gt; and here the content

Comment: It depends how the `initFrame` *handles* the `object_content` data. You might be better off using plain text with `striptags( get_the_content() )`

Comment: it's work thanks but it's give me 3 paragraph, i just the first content, how can i make it limit just one, i mean i just need the content maximum 200 character

Comment: `wp_trim_words( striptags( get_the_content() ), 45 )`, where 45 is the number of words you would like (it's better than character limiting, as this can cut off mid-word!)

Comment: In regards to your other post, you need to `echo` it - `<?php echo wp_trim_words( striptags( get_the_content() ), 45 ) ?>`

Comment: no this one not work, sorry i asked many times because this not for me but for my work :/
but this '<?php echo esc_js( get_the_content() ) ?>', is good for me but i just want to remove img when i see the source
i just want the content, what shall i do?

Comment: it was work but now i got this when i show the source [caption id="attachment_21543" align="aligncenter" width="450"] mark john[/caption] and then the content more than 200 words, i don't know why

Comment: Use `strip_shortcodes` too - see revised answer.